# Multiple commands produce error in react native project build in xcode 12.4

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode12, apple-silicon, react-native-vector-icons

I am trying to add react native vector icons into my react native CLI project and linking it manually with iOS. First, it was giving me some weird errors about "React/RCTDefine.h not found" but I managed to get it but now it is giving Multiple command produce error as you can see below
[image]

I tried multiple solutions from the stack overflow but nothing seems to work for me, I do not know if I am doing them correctly or not, If any expert can help me in this regard please, Thanks in advance